# Questionable statistic - conflict between chi square stat / relative risk reported

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, relative-risk

A recent high profile paper claimed to have found signals of harm from a particular intervention, which to avoid bias I'll refrain from identifying. The methodology is unusual and result controversial for several reasons, but to be fair I was interested in taking the results the authors reported at face value just to check them. So their rate-standardised reported data is as follows:

**Intervention group side-effects**: 67.5 per 10,000

**Placebo group side-effects**: 49.5 per 10,000

From this, the authors claim a relative risk of 1.36 with a 95% confidence interval of 1.02 - 1.83, and they conclude the intervention is more harmful than the placebo, as the risk ratio does not go through unity. I've done a [bit of work](https://elifesciences.org/articles/79573) in the past on result fragility, and did a $\chi^2$ test on their figure, just to check. But in this case, using their reported rate data, you get $\chi^2 \approx 2.76, p \approx 0.0965$, not significant at 5%. If I calculate their 95% confidence interval with this rate data, using

$95\% \space  CI = 1.36 \space \pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{67.5} - \frac{1}{10000}\right) +\left(\frac{1}{49.5} - \frac{1}{10000}\right)}  = 1.36 
\space \pm \space 0.37  $

and in total I get the 95% confidence interval crossing unity (0.99- 1.73) which to me seems consistent with the $\chi^2$ test not being significant at 5%. This to my mind looks like a nothing result. I wrote to the journal to voice this concern, and all I've got is a dismissal that their statistician disagrees. I asked to see this working, but nothing yet. My suspicion is that the authors, while reporting rate data for rare events, used the raw numbers for those calculations. With about 19,000 in each group however, these results will doubtlessly be significant even at marginal differences, which would be misleading without effect size data. Am I correct in believing that this reported result is likely an artefact, or am I missing something? Any thoughts welcome of course!

Comment: "67.5 per 10,000" is not plain count data as required for the $\chi^2$-test (67.5 can't be a count). "Per 10,000" looks like a way to report a proportion with sample size not given, but you'd need to know the sample size in order to correctly run the $\chi^2$-test. Apparently, as I see later, you know the sample size, so you could run the test correctly.

Comment: "With about 19,000 in each group however, these results will doubtlessly be significant even at marginal differences, which would be misleading without effect size data." 67.5/10,000 vs. 49.5/10,000 is basically the estimated effect size. Admittedly their CI is very close to 1 (assuming it's correctly computed) so it can't be ruled out that the effect is very small. I have no idea what counts as a big effect in the field, but it looks like all numbers to figure this  out are given.

Comment: "My suspicion is that the authors, while reporting rate data for rare events, used the raw numbers for those calculations." And they'd be right to do so.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Sure, but then they report the rate data, not the count data in their other results and main text. They even combine rate data at some points. I dug in to get the raw data and I suspect you're right, but they flit between both in the text.